# sign in Button shows as a long button React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried to write my sign in button with  but it does not work when I press it, so I add a flexGrow:1 to its property and it shows the button very long as shown :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntusp.png)

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

const Form: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                   underlineColorAndroid= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                   placeholder= "Phone Number"
                   autoCorrect={true}
                   textContentType="telephoneNumber"
                   keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation"  
                   placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
        />

        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                   underlineColorAndroid= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                   placeholder= "Email"
                   autoCorrect={true}
                   textContentType="emailAddress"
                   keyboardType="email-address"
                   placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
        />

        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                   underlineColorAndroid= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                   placeholder= "Email Password"
                   secureTextEntry={true}
                   placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
        />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  inputBox : {
    width: 400,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)',
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal:16,
    fontSize:14,
    color: '#ffffff',
    marginVertical: 10
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor:'#858585',
    borderRadius: 8,
    flexGrow: 1,
    width:90,
    height:30,
    paddingHorizontal:16,
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingVertical:5
  },
  buttonText:{
    fontSize : 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#ffffff',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});

export default Form;
```

also I tried to use flex instead of flexGrow but its not working also,
removing width:90, height:30, paddingHorizontal:16, marginVertical: 10, and paddingVertical:5 also did not work for me !
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add flexDirection to "row" in your style button style:
So what happens is the the default flex direction is column, hence when you add grow it will grow vertically,

```
button:{
    backgroundColor:'#858585',
    borderRadius: 8,
    flexDirection: 'row'
    flexGrow: 1,
    width:90,
    height:30,
    paddingHorizontal:16,
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingVertical:5
  },
```

OR just add alignSelf to 'stretch' and remove flex grow as shown below

```
button:{
        backgroundColor:'#858585',
        borderRadius: 8,
        alignSelf:'stretch'
        width:90,
        height:30,
        paddingHorizontal:16,
        marginVertical: 10,
        paddingVertical:5
      },
```

Hopefully, this is the answer you are expecting.

Comment: thank you for helping me;  alignSelf:'stretch' worked with me but the button comes to the left and I could not align it to the center hope you have the answer . sorry that's cuz I'm new with JS react native :)

Comment: yes just remove the width:90 from the button style object.

Comment: actually when I move button to the center I couldn't press it, but when it comes to the left or right it work very well

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/HJumgQ2ZI                     I ran your code on snack io could see the click effect and is clickable. What eact issue are you facing. Click on it and you could explain the issue better